# Animation with C++

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, augmented-reality

is there anyway to build rich animation with C++?
I have been using OpenCV for object detection, and I want to show the detected object with rich animation, Is there any easy way to realize this? 
I know flash can be used to easily build rich animation. But can flash be reliably integrated with C++ and How?

Also, Can OpenGL help me with this? To my knowledge, OpenGL is good for 3D rendering. But I am more interested in showing 2D animations in an image. So I am not sure whether this is a right way to go.

Another question, how are those animations in augmented reality realized? What kind of library are they using?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to tell if this answer will be relevant, but depending on what sort of application you are creating you may be able to use [Simple DirectMedia Layer](http://www.libsdl.org/).

This is a cross-platform 2D and 3D (via OpenGL) media library for C, C++ and many other compatible languages.

Comment: Is there any reliable way that I can use flash with C++ together?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you wish to produce an animated demo of your processing results. If I am wrong, let me know.

The simplest way to produce a demo of a vision algorithm is to dump the results to a distinct image file after each processed frame. After the processing session, these individual image files are employed to prepare the video using e.g. mencoder. I employed such procedure to prepare [this](http://www.zemris.fer.hr/~ssegvic/pubs/triangles100915.avi).

Of course, your program can also produce OpenGL. Many people dealing with 3D reconstruction do that. However, in my opinion that would be an overkill for simple 2D detection. Producing flash would be an even greater overkill.

Comment: ssegvic,thank you so much for the answer.Very nice video! By the way, if you do not mind, can you tell me which algorithm you use to detect different signs?  I am very interested in this. Your results look pretty good. For my application right now,I am trying to employ augmented reality onto the detected result. For instance, I am trying to track an object, I want to overlap the object being tracked with a short animation ( the animation can be a flower coming to bloom gradually). I am not sure which is the easiest way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Raw detection is handled by a trained Viola Jones detector, check [1] for details. Raw detections are organized in detection tracks which are obtained by aligning all subsequent detections towards the first one. This last part is currently under review, so I can not further discuss it. [1] http://www.zemris.fer.hr/~ssegvic/pubs/segvic10itsc.pdf

Comment: Hi, ssegvic. Thank you so much for the paper.